# Authorization in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization

I am developing an admin dashboard panel, I have created an intro page for the dashboard which users can log in there
I have four types of user, Admin, SiteManager, PI, and EndUser
After successfully login into the dashboard!
I also Use an Admin Area for something named "Content Management" which is only accessible for the Admin
but when I try to navigate to this content management, it redirects me to the login ( Authorization redirect loops), but the user is already logged in (because I put If condition if the user role is Admin this content management shows)

I am using the individual authentification and scaffold the identity
ASP .Net core 3.1
I don't know how to solve this redirect issue!

in below I put some snip code

```cs
[Authorize(Roles =SD.SuperAdmin)]
[Area("Admin")]
public class HMController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public HMController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

note: the proposed if the condition is in _layout page
and the Admin Area uses another layout(not _layout)!
Also, I have already checked the Sqlserver the roles and the user are created and functional!

the _layout code:

```
 @if (User.IsInRole(SD.SuperAdmin) || User.IsInRole(SD.ManagerUser))
                                {
                                    ...
                                                    @if (User.IsInRole(SD.SuperAdmin))
                                                    {
                                                        ..
                                                    }
                                               ...
                                }
```

Comment: The `Authorize` attribute seems fine to me. Could you add the code of the condition in the `_Layout.cshtml`? And how do you set the role to a user? Do you use `userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role)`?

Comment: I update my question and yes I use user manager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role),
the wired things are the user is already logged in but when to try to go the view of the above controller it redirects me to login (I have tested with [Authorize] but nothing changed @bmartins

Answer (score 0):

If you check for logged user at Login Action and there route user by role. 
You solve this problem

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (GetUserType() == "Admin")
                return Redirect("Admin/Index");
            else if (GetUserType() == "Context")
                return Redirect("Context/Index");
        }
```

For example:

- If admin logged system then if admin click not authorized page then redirect Account/Login.
- Account/Login page is check to user login
- If user logged then redirect user homepage

Comment: where I have to add this?

Comment: Write at login page get action